# Newton's law of viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow, viscosity

I saw that, the shear stress between adjacent fluid layers is proportional to the velocity gradients between the two layers. Did someone know references for empirical test for this law?

Comment: How about roughly 300 years of practical experience with industrial systems involving fluid flo?.

Comment: I want to know how do test, not asking the validate...

Comment: Google "viscometer."